# using if empty , but it needs to see 0 as a item

Tags: php

I am making a enquete for school , and you need to give numbers for each thing , so 0 is a number that is possible , but I use if empty , like this :

```
if (empty($Jurylid) or empty($Organisatie) or empty($Firma) or empty($Standnummer) or empty($Aanmelden) or empty($Ontvangst) or empty($Contact) or empty($Gesprek) or empty($Luisteren) or empty($ProductKennis) or empty($HandelKennis) or empty($Onderhandelen) or empty($TaalGebruik) or empty($Voorkomen)){
    echo "<script>alert('Make sure everything is filled in!')</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location.href='Enquete.php'</script>";

}
```

So how can I make sure it counts 0 as a number ,and not as a empty?
The $Jurylid etc are coming for radio buttons from another page.

Comment: How about counting length of string... strlen()?

Comment: Can you give a real example with my code? My code but with strlen then , because I don't know how to do it with strlen then.

Comment: yes please real code, or tell us where are $Jurylid etc... are coming from

Comment: I edited it where it tells you where it comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace empty by [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

In your case :

```
if (!isset($Jurylid, $Organisatie, $Firma, $Standnummer, $Aanmelden, $Ontvangst, $Contact, $Gesprek, $Luisteren, $ProductKennis, $HandelKennis, $Onderhandelen, $TaalGebruik, $Voorkomen)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Make sure everything is filled in!')</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location.href='Enquete.php'</script>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this , I tought already for replacing it maby with isset , maby I needed to try it first before asking , but still thanks , final somebody here that answers with my example edited :D

Answer (score 0):

What about `!is_numeric()` ? this should work.

Comment: yes. `in_numeric()` return true if it's a number. so `!is_numeric()` will instead of `empty`.

Comment: I think this is your best solution.